# How can I control the number of items are shown in one html?

Tags: python, html, flask

How can I control the number of items are shown in one html?

I want to show 5 items in one html.When I have 21 items,I want to have 5 pages in pagination.I am making Flask app, so I wrote in app.py

```
@app.route("/page", methods=["GET","POST"])
def page():

    users = {
        "data":[
            {
                “Name”:”Tom”,
                “Age”:”21”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”John”,
                “Age”:”40”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Juddy”,
                “Age”:”37”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Kei”,
                “Age”:”46”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Wu”,
                “Age”:”12”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Rey”,
                “Age”:”47”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Boo”,
                “Age”:”25”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Cho”,
                “Age”:”48”
            }
        ],
        “Date”:”20180403”
    }

   users = users["data"]


    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=5)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), search=search)


    return render_template(“index.html", json=users,pagination=pagination)
```

and wrote in index.html

```
<div>
    {% for i in range(json|length) %}
    <div>
            <h3>{{ json[i]['Name'] }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ json[i]['Age'] }}</h3>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}
```

but  now all 8 data is shown in one index.html.I want to show 5 items in one page and 3 items in next page, but what is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: you are pssing the whole users data as json, users = users["data"] and then json=users

Comment: you could strip the length of users using the page no and the list slicing feature in python.

Comment: @ChetanGanji thank you,I can understand your comments, but I cannot write codes to do your comments.Would you show me your message's codes?

Comment: Its not perfect way to do this, but it will work given the simple example, not for production codebase though. I dont know the best way for flask app, as I only work on django.

Comment: Note: cross post to ja.SO (in Japanese) https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44885/19110

Answer (score 0):

```
page = 1 # read the page no dynamically
```

## similar to what you are doing in the below line

## page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=5)

```
pagesize = 5 # always use variable for constants

start = (page - 1) * pagesize # calculation of startpoint of list slicing
end = page * pagesize # calculation of endpoint of list slicing
users = users[start:end]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple pagination object with a class that can group the property data for any page number passed to the route.

First, create the pagination class. This class receives the current page number and returns the users to be listed on that page. The class also reads the source data from a `json` file, although that step can be swapped for a database connection or other custom data selection. Also, the HTML template will need to contain a footer with `previous`, `next`, page, and current page `a href`s, to link all pagination. To do that, special properties are added to the class:

```
import json #only needed if reading data from json file
import collections
def adjust_pagination(f):
  def _wrapper(cls):
    if cls._page_number < 0:
      setattr(cls, '_page_number', 1)
    elif cls._page_number > len(cls._data):
      setattr(cls, '_page_number', len(cls._data))
    return f(cls)

class Pagination:
   def __init__(self, per_page = 5, default = 1, source = json.load(open('filename.txt'))['data']):
     self._data = [source[i:i+per_page] for i in range(0, len(source), per_page)]
     self._page_number = default
   @property
   def next(self):
     return self._page_number + 1 if self._page_number < len(self._data) else len(self._data)
   @property
   def previous(self):
     return self._page_number - 1 if self._page_number > 1 else 1
   @property
   def footer(self):
      atag = collections.namedtuple('atag', ['value', 'iscurrent'])
      return [atag(i+1, i+1 == self._page_number) for i in range(1, len(self._data)+1)]
   @adjust_pagination
   def __iter__(self):
     user = collections.namedtuple('user', ['name', 'age'])
     for _user in self._data[self._page_number-1]:
       yield user(*[_user[i] for i in ['Name', 'Age']])
   def __repr__(self):
       return '/view_users/'
```

Then, create the app with a parameter to receive the desired page:

```
@app.route('/view_users/<page>', methods=['GET'])
def user_pannel(page):
  return flask.render_template('users.html', to_display = Pagination(default=int(page)))
```

Lastly, create `users.html`. For custom pagination `a href` tags, this answer uses bootstrap:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
   <body>
   </body>
    <h1>Current users:</h1>
    {%for user in to_display%}
       <span>Name: {{user.name}}, Age: {{user.age}}</span>
    {%endfor%}
   <div class='spacer' style='height:20px'></div>

  <nav aria-label="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{to_display}}{{to_display.previous}}">Previous</a></li>
      {%for block in to_display.footer%}
        {%if block.iscurrent%}
          <li class="page-item active">
           <a class="page-link" href="{{to_display}}{{block.value}}">{{block.value}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
        {%else%}
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{to_display}}{{block.value}}">{{block.value}}</a></li>
        {%endif%}
     {%endfor%}
     <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="{{to_display}}{{to_display.next}}">Next</a>
     </li>

  </ul>
 </nav>
</html>
```